# How to display a picture with Python on Windows?

Tags: python, image

Running windows 10, writing in Jupiter notebook using python:

I am trying to make an interactive book for my 3 year old nice. For this I wish to show a picture on a touch screen with a question that can be read to her. If she presses the right picture the story should go on, otherwise the question should be repeated. Being a novice programmer ad best though I run in some problems witch I can’t seem to fix by myself. This question being:

How can you take a picture saved in windows and have python use it?

This is a short version of my attempts so far. I choose this one because it seemed the most direct. Basically the end result should be a repeat of this code with different pictures. I have tried other solutions offered on the internet (please see code below), but they run in more or less the same problem

```
print('De salamander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?')
#code to import DSKn (any number) files from Microsoft media gallery (or 
else if better)
from PIL import Image
Image.open('path/to/DSK3.jpg') as img:
    img.show()

This gives the following error:
De salamander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1dd805c10075> in <module>()
      2 #code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if 
better)
      3 from PIL import Image
----> 4 with Image.open('path/to/DSK3.jpg') as img:
      5     img.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2546 
   2547     if filename:
-> 2548         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2549         exclusive_fp = True
   2550 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/DSK3.jpg'
(The print statements are in Dutch, please let me know if a translation is 
needed)
```

It seems that I either need to put the picture in PIL first, this is however nowhere mentiond, or change the path to the file containing the picture. I have tried a literal path, but this gave the same result.

Full code and further attempts:

```
print('Hoe heten ze?')

print('De salander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?')
#code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if better)
from PIL import Image
with Image.open('path/to/DSK3.jpg') as img:
img.show()

print('De slang dacht bomen.Heeft zij gelijk?')
#code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if better)
from PIL import Image
with Image.open('path/to/DSK1.jpg') as img:
    img.show()

print('De kikker dacht bladeren. Heeft zij gelijk?')
#code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if better)
from PIL import Image
with Image.open('path/to/DSK2.jpg') as img:
    img.show()

#code to to click on a picture to select anwaser

image=(input)#pic one = anwsr1 pic two = anwsr2 pic three = anwsr3
while Q1:
    if image is DSK1:
       print('De kikker had het goed')
       break
   if image is DSK2: 
       print('De slang had het fout')
   if image is DSK3:
       print('De salamander had het fout')
   else:
      print('')

Hoe heten ze?
De salander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-284f197fb200> in <module>()
      4 #code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if 
better)
      5 from PIL import Image
----> 6 with Image.open('path/to/DSK3.jpg') as img:
      7     img.show()
      8

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2546 
   2547     if filename:
-> 2548         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2549         exclusive_fp = True
   2550 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/DSK3.jpg'
```

Next code:

```
print('Hoe heten ze?')

print('De salander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?')
#code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if better)
from simshow import simshow
simshow('some_local_file.DSK2')  # display from local file

print('De slang dacht bomen.Heeft zij gelijk?')
#code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if better)
from simshow import simshow
simshow('some_local_file.DSK1')  # display from local file

print('De kikker dacht bladeren. Heeft zij gelijk?')
#code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if better)
from simshow import simshow
simshow('some_local_file.DSK3')  # display from local file

#code to to click on a picture to select anwaser

image=(input)#pic one = anwsr1 pic two = anwsr2 pic three = anwsr3
while Q1:
    if image is DSK1:
        print('De kikker had het goed')
        break
    if image is DSK2: 
       print('De slang had het fout')
    if image is DSK3:
       print('De salamander had het fout')
    else:
       print('')

Hoe heten ze?
De salander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d0f9fcf9036a> in <module>()
      3 print('De salander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?')
      4 #code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if 
better)
----> 5 from simshow import simshow
      6 simshow('some_local_file.DSK2')  # display from local file
      7 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simshow'
Next code:

    print('Hoe heten ze?')
    print('De salander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?')
    #code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if 
better)
    import os.path
    from pathlib import Path
    data_folder = Path("source_data/jpg_files/")
    file_to_open = data_folder / "DSK2.jpg"
    f = open(DSK2)
    print(f.read())
    print('De slang dacht bomen.Heeft zij gelijk?')
    #code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if 
better)
    from pathlib import Path
    data_folder = Path("source_data/jpg_files/")
    file_to_open = data_folder / "DSK1.jpg"
    f = open(DSK1)
    print(f.read())
    print('De kikker dacht bladeren. Heeft zij gelijk?')
    #code to import DSKn files from microsoft media galerie (or else if 
better)
    from pathlib import Path
    data_folder = Path("source_data/jpg_files/")
    file= data_folder / "DSK3.jpg"
    f = open(DSK3)
    print(f.read())
    #code to to click on a picture to select anwaser
    image=(input)#pic one = anwsr1 pic two = anwsr2 pic three = anwsr3
    while Q1:
        if image is DSK1:
            print('De kikker had het goed')
            break
       if image is DSK2: 
           print('De slang had het fout')
       if image is DSK3:
          print('De salamander had het fout')
       else:
          print('')

Hoe heten ze?
```

### De salander dacht wolken. Heeft hij gelijk?

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3448e8e4d945> in <module>()
      6 data_folder = Path("source_data/jpg_files/")
      7 file_to_open = data_folder / "DSK2.jpg"
----> 8 f = open(DSK2)
      9 print(f.read())
     10 print('De slang dacht bomen.Heeft zij gelijk?')

NameError: name 'DSK2' is not defined
```

I have tried other code, but have those no longer saved (overwritten)

Comment: Your first examples are just saying they can't find a file at the path you gave. Do you know what the correct value of `path/to/DSK3.jpg` is? Is it definitely spelled correctly, and given as an absolute path? If it's a relative path, it may not be correct for the working directory of your program. You can easily check using `open`, or `os.stat`.

Comment: Try checking the path first with `os.path.exists()`, or it is probably better to use absolute path. Or, `Path.resolve()`.

Comment: When you say *"take a picture saved in windows and have python use it?"* you merely mean *"display a JPG image in Python"*, not *"automate taking a Windows screenshot"*. Another subpart of your question is finding the correct Windows path to the image.

Comment: You may find **matplotlib** package is easier for this purpose. There are many existing questions on *"display image in matplotlib"*